# In Ionic Slider, the pager doesn't show in IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

As you can see from the images, the pager does not show in the IOS version of my Ionic App. The code must be right because its there in Android. Is there something I am missing?

```
<ion-slides pager="true" scrollbar="true">
```

**Android**
[image: android and browser]

**IOS**
[image: IOS]

Comment: ionic version please

Comment: version 5, sorry ("@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",)

Comment: Can you try to debug using the devtools of Safari or chrom (emulate iPhone) and check the actual component's css is there and you can manipulate it?

Comment: in chrome if I emulate iphone, all looks good. I can see it. When I put in actual iphone, no

Comment: In Safari, same behavior as IOS, so I tried your suggestion. Everything was the same except, ``` <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-bullets"><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active"></span><span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span></div> ``` the contents of this DIV was blank in Safari

Comment: @ibrahim-awad I just realized something else, if I change orientation of phone, it appears, I guess Ionic redraws?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its ideal, but seems when I copied the options from here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#coverflow it worked. I assumed it would work with simple setup as I didn't need any other options...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order in which components are rendered can affect the `ios-slides` pager in iOS, so you could try to make sure that it always renders at the end.

One workaround would be initializing a variable after the view is entered:

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
      this.viewEntered = true;
  }
```

And use it in your `ion-slides` to decide when to show it:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" *ngIf="viewEntered">
...
</ion-slides>
```